# I using PUT method but keep showing not allowed

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

`Controller`

```
public function edit(Product $product)
{
return view('products_update', compact('product'));
}

    public function edit(Product $product) { return view('products_update', compact('product')); }
    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'desc' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'qty' => 'required',
            // Add more validation rules for other fields if needed
        ]);
    
        // Update the product
        $newTitle = $request->input('product_title');
        $newDesc= $request->input('product_desc');
        $newPrice= $request->input('product_price');
        $newQty= $request->input('product_qty');
    
        // Update other fields if needed
        //$product->save();
    
        DB::update('update products set title = ?, desc = ?, price = ?, qty = ? where id = ?', 
        [$newTitle, $newDesc, $newPrice, $newQty]);
    
        // Redirect to the index page or show a success message
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success', 'Product updated successfully.');
    }
```

`blade`

```
<form action="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}" method="post">
    @method('PUT')
    <!-- <input type="hidden" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> -->
    @csrf
```

`route`

```
Route::get('/products/{product}/edit', \[ProductController::class,'edit'\])-\>name('products.edit');
Route::put('/products/{id}', \[ProductController::class, 'update'\])-\>name('products.update');
```

Comment: It will be `{{ route('products.update', ['id' => $product->id]) }}`

Comment: @tf after changing to what you say, the update button canot be function. It just stick on the page

Answer (score 1):

first of all you must check on your route name. currently you're using `<form action="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}" method="post">`. but actually your route name is `products.update` for update data.

Based on your route `Route::put('/products/{id}', \[ProductController::class, 'update'\])-\>name('products.update');`

So, you must change your currently action form

from `action="{{ route('products.edit', $product->id) }}"`

into `action="{{ route('products.update', $product->id) }}"`

.

And the last things, if the update button cannot be function. It just stick on the page like you said before, make sure you have `<button type="submit">` inside your `<form></form>` to submit your update data

Comment: i did cahnge to products.update, and i checked for the button in under type of submit, still not working

Comment: i think that's so weird. have you dd() inside of your update function? to make sure that your form action is executing update function

Comment: not success. i have no ideas now

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'product_title' => 'required',
        'product_desc' => 'required',
        'product_price' => 'required|numeric',
        'product_qty' => 'required',
        // Add more validation rules for other fields if needed
    ]);

    // Retrieve the product from the database
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    // Update the product attributes with the validated data
    $product->title = $request->product_title;
    $product->desc = $request->product_desc;
    $product->price = $request->product_price;
    $product->qty = $request->product_qty;

    // Update other fields if needed
    $product->save();

    // Redirect to the index page or show a success message
    return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success', 'Product updated successfully.');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).